# Magento Graphql Cache issue

Tags: magento2, cache, graphql, pwa-studio, fastly

I have an issue with Magento graphql cache.
Magento PWA setup is on Magento cloud.
Default graphql query cache is not working with fastly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Graphql needs cache to be flushed, every time you make any changes in your graphql

Comment: Did you found any solution?